# Tinymce в django не показывает редактор

Tags: python, django

Установил [django-tinymce](https://github.com/jazzband/django-tinymce) и установил [по инструкции](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#id2). Но при вызове формы, не появляется tinymce редактор.

Я так понял мне надо добавить в static js файл? где его взять?
если нет, тогда как правильно указать путь к js файлу?

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ServiceCRM3/static'),]
#
# TINYMCE
#
STATIC_JS_DIR = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_JS_DIR, "tiny_mce")
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(TINYMCE_JS_ROOT, "tiny_mce.js")
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "theme": "silver",
    "height": 500,
    "menubar": False,
    "plugins": "advlist,autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,print,preview,anchor,"
    "searchreplace,visualblocks,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,paste,"
    "code,help,wordcount",
    "toolbar": "undo redo | formatselect | "
    "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter "
    "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | "
    "removeformat | help",
}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Prints    

    class SimplePrintAddForm(forms.ModelForm):        
        class Meta:
            model = Prints
            fields = ['name', 'contentform']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class Prints(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Nazvanie')
    contentform = HTMLField()
   

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_prints', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

**Так выглядит форма**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `collectstatic` пробовали?

Comment: да, не помогло. можете глянуть вторую ветку? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1307628/295536