# не работает редактор ckeditor в django

Tags: python, django

**не работает ckeditor за пределами админки, не показывает поля редактирования итд.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- установил по инструкции https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#installation
- `collectstatic`, после изменения `models` `makemigrations`, `migrate`
- тут указано https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#id9, что для работы с полями за пределами `admin`, надо добавлять статические файлы html, но не помогло

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    ]
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ServiceCRM3/static'),]
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'height': 300,
        'width': 300,
    },
}
```

**models.py**

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Prints(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Nazvanie')
    contentform = RichTextUploadingField()
```

**forms**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Prints
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class SimplePrintAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    contentform = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Prints
        fields = ['name', 'contentform']
```

**html**

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>

    <form action="{% url 'print_add'%}?category={{ tag }}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formOne.non_field_errors }}
        {{ formOne }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить form</button>
    </form>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: `{{ formOne.media }}` ?

Comment: помогло, спасибо